# kustomization directory apparently not accepted under resources

Tags: kustomize

I have a kustomize overlay that refers to its base in its kustomization file `overlays/test/kustomization.yaml` as follows:

```
resources:
  - ../../base
```

The relevant directory structure is as follows:

```
<some_path>/base/kustomization.yaml
<some_path>/overlays/test/kustomization.yaml
```

When I try `kubectl kustomize overlays/test` the following error occurs:

> err="accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources
> from '../../base': '<some_path>/base' must resolve to a file':
> recursed accumulation of path '/base'

The documentation for `resources` says:

> Each entry in this list must be a path to a file, or a path (or URL)
> referring to another kustomization directory,

If I am not mistaken, `/<some_path>/base` should be a valid kustomization directory, because `/<some_path>/base/kustomization.yaml` exists. So why must the path resolve to a file (not: directory) according to the error message? What am I missing?

Comment: That all looks fine. Can you update your question to include (a) the output of `tree` when run in the `<some_path>` directory (or `find . -type f -print` if you don't have `tree`), (b) the contents of `base/kustomization.yaml`, and (c) the version of kustomize you're using?

Comment: @larks Thanks for your suggestions. I've meanwhile been able to resolve this. I was about to delete my question, but because of your interaction I'm now going to answer it myself. Maybe it's worth recording it in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was meanwhile able to resolve this. There was a stupid mistake in `<some_path>/base/kustomization.yaml`, so `kubectl kustomize overlays/test` failing was apparently an indirect effect of `kubectl kustomize base` failing as well.